# Converting integers representing time periods to time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with time periods in the second column. Every period represents 30 minutes and it goes all the way up to 48 periods (24 hours). Is there some way to change the integers representing the periods into a time format and concatenate it with the date column for a full datetime? E.g. 1 becomes 00:30, 2 becomes 01:00, 3 becomes 01:30 and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the DATE column to datetime and add a timedelta of 30 minutes multiplied by PERIOD.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':['2015-01-03', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-03'],
                   'PERIOD':[1,2,3]})

df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']) + df['PERIOD'] * pd.Timedelta(30, unit='min')

# df
#          DATE  PERIOD            DATETIME
# 0  2015-01-03       1 2015-01-03 00:30:00
# 1  2015-01-03       2 2015-01-03 01:00:00
# 2  2015-01-03       3 2015-01-03 01:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver!